# узнать какой модуль определяет типы

Tags: delphi, типы-данных

Вопрос теоретический, не могу проверить.

Есть прога Delphi (10.3), в ней подключены модули

```
uses m1 {там type tm000=string}, m2 {там type tm000=integer};

type tm000=byte; {local}

var v:tm000;

begin
// тут узнать тип переменной v
end;
end.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всегда будет использоваться тип определенный в текущем модуле. Затем используются типы из подключаемых подмодулей справа налево. Т.е. сначала из m2, затем m1.

Если требуется использовать все типы в одном модуле, то необходимо указать имя модуля.

```
var 
  v:tm000;
  v1:m2.tm000;
  v2:m1.tm000;
```

Comment: круто, не знал. а вот тут можно узнать модуль и тип? // тут узнать тип переменной v

Comment: Для наследников `TObject` можно узнать много информации, включая имя модуля. Для скалярных типов вроде нет, не исследовал этот вопрос.

Comment: ответ приемлем. но у мну более приземленные мысли. Можно ли это понять в коде, мой первый пост, между begin\end? Например: if v as (m1) and (type as tm000) then AlexR('Best'); ? Т.е. модули уже подключены. Теорию Вы описали. Теперь надо узнать, кто откуда программно.

Comment: С ходу не скажу. Такое работает для объектов. Фантазируя: если у них разный размер и мы знаем какой, то можно отличить, используя функцию `SizeOf`

Comment: я читал, что есть какая-то функция(может не одна), определяющая тип, типа IsInt(v).. а для модуля такой нет?

Comment: Я даже про `IsInt` не слышал. В штатной поставке ничего похожего нет.

Comment: это я для примера.. ща..

Comment: точно помню что было. вот ща первое в гуглах - использовать юнит вариант(variant) и вроде в нем было, это первое что быстро нашел. ++ f VarType(V) and VarArray = VarArray then

Comment: Это немного не то

Comment: для типа переменной пойдет. а вот какой модуль инициировал тип.. я что-то припоминаю, давно занимался. ок, если что, сообщу, вопрос в закладки. еще раз спасибо. жиглов говорил - запишем в загадки.